# Node js search on prisma for string with case insensitivity

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I want to find the user with a specific email regardless case sensitivity of the email in the DB or in the request body. Using any of the following methods is rendering an undefined function error

```
    const user = await prisma.User.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: {
                insensitive: {
                    equals: req.body.email,
                },
            }
        }
    })

    const user = await prisma.User.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: {
                insensitiveEquals: req.body.email
            }
        }
    })

    const user = await prisma.User.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email,
            mode: 'insensitive'
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you share what exact error are you getting? Maybe share the stack trace?
Have you executed `npx prisma generate` to generate Prisma Client? Also can you share the user model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined function error would mean that there is no function `findUnique` available on the `user` model.
This would happen if `PrismaClient` is not up to date with the schema file.
You would need to execute `npx prisma generate` to generate the latest `PrismaClient`.

After generating PrismaClient following query can be used to find user with email in case `insensitive` mode.

```
  const user = await prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
      email: {
        equals: 'test@test.com',
        mode: 'insensitive',
      },
    },
  });
```

This reference of [case insensitive filtering](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/case-sensitivity#options-for-case-insensitive-filtering) will be helpful as well.